# c# using checkbox from form2 in form1

Tags: c#, checkbox, reference

Okay, this is a simple question, but it's been racking my brain for a while now.

I have two forms: `Form1`and `Form2`.

I have some checkboxes on `Form2`, and I want to use data from checked check boxes on `Form2` on `Form1` but when I add the following code on `Form1` it's giving me errors:

```
if (cbTESTING.Checked) 
{
    uri_testings += string.Format("{0}.TESTINGS,", word);
}
```

I'm getting an error with cbTESTING as it's not referenced on `Form1`.

How can I use or reference checkboxes from `Form2` in `Form1`?

Comment: How do the forms relate?  Does `Form1` have a `form2` variable of type `Form2`?

Comment: as of right now they don't relate at all, but im wanting to use the functions from the check boxes on form2 in form1.

Comment: You could simply add public methods to the form to return the variable values, no?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I do not think that is what helps because he has a problem of access.
@Dzje I edited my answer concerning the connection between these two forms. As I mentioned there, if you have them totally **unrelated** then you have to start communication between them, either by `sockets` and `events` or using `WCF`. If one of them creates the other it would be easier for us to help you either by my answer in the case of `Form1` creating `Form2` or I can tell you if it was the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by making the checkboxes save values in the properties settings default and then calling them that way as every time i wanted to open the program instead of having to click them again it's auto saved my current values.

Thank you all for your help though.

Here is some code for future reference if anyone else wanted to do it the way I did.

Here is the code that saves it to the settings.

```
            if (cbTESTING.Checked)
            Properties.Settings.Default.cbTESTING = true;
        else
            Properties.Settings.Default.cbTESTing = false;
```

and here was the code to call that in a different form.

```
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.cbTESTING == true)
            {
                uri_domains += string.Format("{0}.testing,", word);
            }
```

Hope this will help someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty clean way to fix this.. just change the access modifier to `public` for `cbTESTING` in the designer for `Form2`.

That is, in Form2.Designer.cs, change

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox cbTESTING;
```

to

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox cbTESTING;
```

Then, `Form1` can look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitalizeComponent();

        Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
        bool isChecked = secondForm.cbTESTING.checked;
    }
}
```

**Edits:** removed `protected` solution, which isn't a great option in this case.

Comment: `protected` works for inherited classes, `Form1` should be inheriting `Form2` not otherwise because `Form1` is using `Form2`.

Comment: I was confused by the use of `protected` which lead me wrongly. `protected` would not work anyway. However, in your solution using `public` it kind of looks like my solution, but now `Form1 : Form` and `Form2 : Form` because it is accessing its instance public variable.

Comment: @AmmarSalman I just spent some time fiddling around in Visual Studio, and it turns out I desperately needed a lesson on access modifiers before trying to suggest how to use them to other people. I've completely removed the `protected` part from my answer because I agree that it's not the best option for this case.

Comment: Yeah, I do not think it could work in the first place because it will try accessing a `field`/`property` from the `base` class which does not really help because the `base` class is a `source` not `instance` and we need to access the `instance` that already exists. Anyway, in my answer I made an edit on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

Since `Form1` creates `Form2`, and `Form1` needs to manipulate `Form2` then you can change this from Form2.Designer.cs:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox cbTESTING;
```

To:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox cbTESTING;
```

Assuming in `Form1` you created `Form2` like this:

```
Form2 f2 = Form2();
f2.Show();
```

Then you use this to check `cbTESTING`:

```
if(f2.cbTESTING.Checked) // do stuff  ;
```

---

**EDIT:** I have seen your comment which says they do not relate to each other at all which makes it impossible to achieve in any easy method. What you said implies communication between these two THREADS since each `Form` runs in a `Thread` and these threads are unrelated. Communication is NOT an easy thing to do, you can try it using `UDP` and `Events` but trust me, having a direct relation between them would make things MUCH easier for you.

Anyway, I would assume some other `Form` or `Thread` would launch these `Forms`?

Comment: I saw your comment, and immediately made these exact revisions a couple of minutes ago. I made an error distinguishing between protected and public, but have fixed that in my answer. Thanks for catching my mistake!

Comment: Alright, I am not sure the first method works, I will remove it anyway. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Residual typo; I had them flipped from my original post. Please make sure it's correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant solution but will definitely work. Declare a public static bool variable in Form2. Add Checkbox changed event to your checkboxes and change those static variables accordingly. Then just check those variable in Form1 such as `Form2.VariableName` let me know if you need further explanation

*Edit*

In Form2 declare `public static bool CheckBoxStatus = false;` false by default, you can change that.

Also in Form2 add following event `checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckedChanged)` and add appropriate function such as

```
private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxStatus = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

And Finally in Form1 one you can simply check if that checkbox is checked like this

```
if(Form2.CheckBoxStatus == true) ;
else ;
```

Hope that helps.
*PS sorry my formatting, new to posting answers here.

Comment: Hey, would appreciate very much if you could give an example explanation on this.

Comment: Edited my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a ugly way to do what you want:

```c#
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();

        label1.Text = frm.TextBoxChecked;
    }
}

//Just declare a prop into Form2 a set it with the value you need
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string TextBoxChecked { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            TextBoxChecked = "Checkbox_1_checked";
        else
            TextBoxChecked = "Checkbox_1_unchecked";
    }
}
```

Lets do things in a cool way.
Maybe a good aproache is to say to Form2: "Hey you, when your checkbox change let me know", It sounds like a callback. So let do it:

```c#
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void doWhenCheckBoxChange(string text)
    {
        //I'm receiving the notification indicating that the checkbox has changed
        label1.Text = text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form2();
        //I'm passing a callback to Form2, Here is where I say 
        //"Hey you, let me know where your checkbox change"
        frm.DoWhenCheckboxChange = doWhenCheckBoxChange;
        frm.ShowDialog();

        //label1.Text = frm.TextBoxChecked;
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //public string TextBoxChecked { get; set; }
    public Action<string> DoWhenCheckboxChange;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TextBoxChecked = "Checkbox_1";
        //Notify to Form1 that checkbox has changed.
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            DoWhenCheckboxChange("Checkbox_1_checked");
        else
            DoWhenCheckboxChange("Checkbox_1_unchecked");
    }
}
```

If you test the second aproache, you will discover that you dont need to close your Form2 to see the changes.